# I want an animation such that this window move from right to left

Tags: animation, blend-modes

[image: Wall Image]

[image: Window Image]

I want an animation video of it can anyone help me...

Comment: If you are a new user to Blender you may want to see video tutorials at a video site. I would search - Blender Tutorials texture mapping - at a site such as you tube.  This site is not a tutorial site.  I am not sure I understand your question.  Please know this site wants you to have clarity in you question.  I may what you meant guess in a subsequent answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is nothing more than a "Do this for me" request. - No please!

Answer (score 1):

- Assume Blender Render. Create two planes.  UV unwrap and select your textures in the question above to be mapped to the planes via the material panel then texture panel.
- Go to a beginning frame and insert position keyframes for both planes
- Go to a ending frame and insert position keyframes for both planes
- Your materials can be Shadowless.
- Test animation. Render your animation to a video format.